# Cannot add folders and files to Windows Installer package

Tags: windows, installation, package

I' m using Visual Studio to create windows installer package, i can't add the folders and data files needed for the application. I create the folders needed for the application in the 'application folder'(under 'File System on Target Machine'), then add files into the appropriate folders, and when i install the application and go to the installation folder there are no folders...there is only the application exe file, hm...

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, i forgot to put the files in the folders actually, that was the problem, so if the folder is empty it is not created in the installer package.